# Wordpress admin only shows text

Tags: wordpress

my wordpress admin only shows text, What maybe the cause of this and how can i fix it? 
i attach a photo of the error

[image]

Comment: Hi please reinstall wp-admin and wp-include folder the version which you used and check.

Comment: yes i already done that, but after 2mins it goes back to that error.
what may have cause this?

Comment: try to use another server or hosting if issue persist then the server may stop wp-admin scripts and css

Answer (score 0):

First step:

Enable WP_DEBUG https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

in wp-config.php file, so that you can see useful error.

If it wont works then copy the wp-admin and wp-includes folders from a fresh install of same version.

Comment: I have added the debug but no errors are prompt, I already done coping the wp-admin and wp-include from the fresh install wordpress site, but after it works but the pages are gone, but after 2 mins i think it goes back to the same problem the image i uploaded above.

Comment: you are doing it on local or some live server? and make sure your console is showing no errors after login to wp-admin

Comment: on live server. when i go to wp-login it display blank

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be caused by a Script Blocker plugin. Disable all the plugins and clear cache cookies, then hard-refresh the page in your Browser by pressing Ctrl+F5 so everything is reloaded each time and you don’t get cached pages and old results.

Comment: Hi I have done what you have told thank by the way, but the problem is still not fix

Answer (score 0):

If you are using debian, ubuntu, linux mint and php7 this command will fix your issue

```
sudo apt install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and adding the following line to wp-config.php solved it--

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );